# DropdownList Doesn't Work on Mobile Devices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 dropdown list in my page. In web browser (PC side) It works fine. There is no problem. When i open the page with chrome toogle device toolbar and i resize as mobile view, it only gives this error

```
fastclick.js:1 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080
```

csHTML Code

```
<div class="tab-pane active tabcontent" id="reservationPage" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group row rowR">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-2"><strong>Yemekhane</strong>  </label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RefectoryId, new SelectList(Model.Refectories, "Id", "Name"), ("Seçiniz"), new { Id = "RefectoryId", @class = "form-control select2" })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row rowR">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-2"><strong>Öğün</strong>  </label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FoodMealId, new SelectList(Model.FoodMeals, "Id", "Name"), ("Seçiniz"), new { Id = "FoodMealId", @class = "form-control select2" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
    <script>
    var reservationCount = 0;
    var totalAmount = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#reservationCount")[0].textContent = "(" + reservationCount + ")";


        //İlk açıldığında rezervasyon sayfasının acık gelmesi için
        var tablinks = document.getElementById("reservationPageHead");
        tablinks.className = tablinks.className + " active";
        document.getElementById('reservationPage').style.display = "block";


        //var foodMealId = $("#FoodMealId").val();
        //var refectoryId = $("#RefectoryId").val();
        //GetCalendarMenuPartial(foodMealId, refectoryId);



        $("#RefectoryId").select2({
            allowClear: true,
            placeholder: 'Yemekhane Seçiniz',
            // dropdownParent: $(".bootbox-body"),
        });

        var refectorySelect = $('#RefectoryId');
        refectorySelect.on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var foodMealId = $("#FoodMealId").val();
            var refectoryId = $("#RefectoryId").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetRefectoryWithFoodMeal", "Reservation", new { area = "Common" })",
                        data: { refectoryId: refectoryId },
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        success: function (returnData) {
                          if (returnData.data == undefined) {
                               PageToastr(returnData.type, returnData.message, returnData.title);
                          }
                          else {
                               //FoodMeal List
                              $("#FoodMealId option[value]").remove();
                              $("#FoodMealId").select2({
                                  allowClear: true,
                                  placeholder: 'Seçiniz',
                                  data : returnData.data,
                              });
                          }
                      },
                      beforeSend: function () {
                          $(".loaderDiv").show();
                          $(".loader").show();
                      },
                      complete: function () {
                          $(".loaderDiv").hide();
                          $(".loader").hide();
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                        if (xhr.status === 999) {
                            noAuthorize(this.url);
                        }
                      }
            });
            var foodMealId = $("#FoodMealId").val();
            var refectoryId = $("#RefectoryId").val();
            GetCalendarMenuPartial(foodMealId, refectoryId);
        });

        $("#FoodMealId").select2({
            allowClear: true,
            placeholder: 'Öğün Seçiniz',
            //dropdownParent: $(".bootbox-body"),
        });

        var foodMealSelect = $('#FoodMealId');
        foodMealSelect.on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var foodMealId = $("#FoodMealId").val();
            var refectoryId = $("#RefectoryId").val();
            GetCalendarMenuPartial(foodMealId, refectoryId);
        });


        // Rezervasyonu tamamla için tooltip
        $('#completeReservation').tooltip('update');
    });
</script>

<script>
    function GetCalendarMenuPartial(foodMealId, refectoryId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("NewReservationCalendarMenuPartial", "Reservation", new { area = "Common" })',
                data: { foodMealId: foodMealId, refectoryId: refectoryId, addCardMenu: $("#AddCardMenuString").val() },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (partialPage) {
                    if (partialPage.title != undefined) {
                        PageToastr(partialPage.type, partialPage.message, partialPage.title);
                        if (partialPage.result == '@Enums.ResultStatus.SessionTimeExpired.ToString()') {
                            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = '/Login/Login'; }, 5000)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#calendarMenuPartial").html(partialPage);
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".loaderDiv").show();
                    $(".loader").show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $(".loaderDiv").hide();
                    $(".loader").hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    if (xhr.status === 999) {
                        noAuthorize(this.url);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

After that I've added touch-action: none; but it doesn't work too. It works properly in PC Devices. But never works on mobile devices.